# PHP regex help. preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have four words `A,B,C,D`.
I want to replace all occurrences of `A B` or `A C` with `A D` in given sentence.

I have written this `preg_replace("/([A])\s[C|B]/i", "\1 D",$sentence);`

But it is not giving correct output. Where I am going wrong?

Comment: What does the sentence look like? It can give us a clue why your pattern "does not work". Actually, the `"\1 D"` should be changed as shown below to `'\1 D'` or `"\\1 D"`, but that might be just a part of your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\` within `"` are escaping the string special characters, not the regexp special characters. Either you `'` as string delimiter or double `\` characters:

```
preg_replace('/([A])\s[C|B]/i', '\1 D', $sentence);
```

Comment: FYI, "string special characters" are usually referred to as *escape sequences* (like `\r`, `\n`, etc.)